# Lambda in Typescript behaving weird

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-5

I have the following statement as part of a bigger class:

```
array.map(seq => this.mFunction(seq));
```

this compiles (with the help of tsc command) to:

```
array.map(function (seq) { return _this.mFunction(seq); });
```

Okay all looks good...
But why does then:

```
array.map(seq => { this.mFunction(seq); });
```

compile into:

```
array.map(function (seq) { _this.mFunction(seq); });
```

I have actually gotten problems in a project where the first way of writing was OK but the second made the webpage break in lots of ways (I'm using Angular)...
I always thought those were exactly the same..

This is from my tsconfig:

```
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"target": "es5"
```

Comment: Because Arrow functions are defined that way. In JS, this has nothing to do with the Typescript compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lambda body isn't enclosed in braces, then the body is treated as an expression whose value is to be returned, so TypeScript adds a `return` keyword. If the lambda body is enclosed in braces, then the body is treated as a statement block to be executed, and you are responsible for including any necessary `return` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The first version, one line arrow functions, have an implicit return, since you do not use `{` and `}` around the function body.

So the second version needs to be `array.map(seq => { return this.mFunction(seq); });` to be equivalent to the first.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` means compiler expects you to have a return statement inside the block

```js
array.map(seq => this.mFunction(seq)); 
// implecit return . 
// the compiler adds return by default if there is no {} and one statement is present ... so here return is added
```

```js
array.map(seq => { this.mFunction(seq); });
// the compiler expects you to have return statement by yourself 
// so compiler is not adding return statement .
```